# Get all the columns in a database at once in sql/apex

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have a database called "cihe" is it possible to select all columns in the data base at once just the columns?(ps) im useing oracle apex to do this if it helps

Comment: All columns in all tables or just all columns in a table?

Comment: all columns in all tables

Comment: not the data just the column names

Comment: @user3841039 Do you want the data or just the names of all columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
```

You may also check [ALL_TAB_COLUMNS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2091.htm)